# Determining delimeter for a structured section in a text file using a hex viewer

Tags: hex, delimiter

I have a text file with structured data. After each text block it says "END" and continues onto the next block. Looking at a hex viewer I see

```
0A:45:4E:44:0A:20:20:20:20:20:20:20:20:20
```

which translates into

```
?END?
```

Notice the 9 spaces.

How do I write this as a delimeter in my code?

```
"END\n\n\n \n \n \n \n \n \n"
```

This doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely,

```
"\nEND\n         "
```

however you forgot to mention which language you're using. Where did up get all those extra `\n`s from?

Comment: I stripped out all the extra \n's. Thanks!